# localStorage not storing value as I want it

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.id]: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/validateAccount', {
      "username": this.state.username,
      "password": this.state.password
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
        if(response === 'success') {
          localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true');
          console.log(response.data);
        }

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);

      });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  checkStorage() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('loggedin'))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input id="username" type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} /> <br></br>
        </label>

        <label>
          Password
          <input id="password" type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} /> <br></br>

        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        <div id="typehere"></div>



      </form>
      <button onClick={this.checkStorage}>test</button>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default login;
```

I'm currently practicing react js and I am trying to imitate the PHP $_SESSION['some-value'] function which is basically it saves the session value until you terminate it (logout) with session_destroy().

I think localStorage is exactly that however it's not saving it? Above is a working login form, if I put a valid username password then it gets to console.log("success") and "loggedin" is set to true in local storage. Now if I use the button "test" it would get "loggin" from local storage and should return true but it returns null instead. Why?

[image]

I logged in with a valid account got "success" then quicked test immediately after and it returned "null". Anyway to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason it's failing is this part of your code:

```
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)                  // <---  This indicates `response` is an object, not a string
    if(response === 'success') {                // <---  This expects `response` to be a string
      localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'true');
      console.log(response.data);
    }

  })
```

Make sure you are checking the correct item in the `if (...)`.  I'm guessing you meant to test `response.data === 'success'` instead of `response === 'success'`

Comment: I just realised I had two console.logs oops. This fixed it. After further searching I came across sessionStorage as well and I'm wondering what is the difference. For logins should you typically have sessions or local storages?

Comment: sessionStorage only lasts as long as the window is open and can only be accessed by the window that set it.  @sssss glad to help

Answer (score -1):

Try using it as ,

localStorage.setItem('loggedin', true);

and while getting the value -> JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedin"))

Reason is, local storage stores everything in string format, even your Boolean value will get saved as 'true', 'false', so either you need to check the string or use JSON.parse to convert it to Boolean again

Comment: OP is not storing a boolean and regardless does not explain a value returned of `null`